# Can't duplicate function

Tags: typescript, react-native, function, duplicates, navigation

When I try to duplicate function
it show RootNavigator error

> Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393)

I try add export at the top but won't work

```
export {}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#options

```
const DashboardStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <DashboardStack.Navigator>
      <DashboardStack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <DashboardStack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
      <DashboardStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
      </DashboardStack.Group>
    </DashboardStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const ActivityStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <DashboardStack.Navigator>
      <DashboardStack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <DashboardStack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
      <DashboardStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
      </DashboardStack.Group>
    </DashboardStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. You have to give them different names.

Comment: how do I give these different names can you give an example of these?

Comment: Instead of `function RootNavigator() {`, name it something else, like `function DashboardNavigator() {`.  The `function` keyword tells Javascript to create a variable that holds a function.